# Oxyplot for Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, oxyplot

I have plotted a graph in Xamarin Android using the trial Library of TreeChart. But the full version is expensive. I now want to use something that is free. I thought of using Oxyplot.

I added a reference to the NuGet package of Oxyplot.Android in Xamarin to my project. But I dont know how to use it.

There is no documentation for the same on their official website. Can anyone let me know of any tutorial or Demo project which I can refer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On [Github](https://github.com/oxyplot) you can find these documentation or examples for android,iOS,Xamarin,WP,silverlight,.NEt.

Also this [link](http://resources.oxyplot.org/examplebrowser/) give full documentation...